# Posting values to a C# webapi method from typescript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript

I have a class in typescript as shown below,

```
class Suggestion {

    Id: number;
    Description: string;
    Priority: string;
    CreatedByNTLogin: string;
    CreatedDateTime: Date;
    CurrentStatus: string;
    Code: string;

    View(): any {

        return $.ajax({
            url: 'api/Suggestion/View',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
        });
    }

    Submit(): any {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'api/Suggestion/Submit',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: this
        });
    }
}
```

And I am invoking the submit function as shown below,

```
    var suggestion = new Suggestion();

    suggestion.Code = CodeDdl.val();
    suggestion.Priority = suggestionPriorityDdl.val();
    suggestion.Description = suggestionDescriptionTxtBox.val();
    suggestion.CurrentStatus = "New";

    $.when(suggestion.Submit()).done(function () {
         //todo
    }).fail(function () {
         //todo
        }).always(function () {
         //todo
    });
```

With the above code, I am getting the following exception on the JavaScript side and the call never reached the controller method.

> // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
>         // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if
>   not included)         return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );     }

I see that the 'this' object in Submit() method has the necessary values before ajax post.

**Note:** The View() method in typescript works fine and I am able to retrieve the values from controller method.

How to fix this issue? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using jQuery in no-conflict mode somewhere else, or an additional different version of jQuery?

Comment: I am using jquery-2.1.4.js as an additional version.